# Pandas hierarchical pivot get column with max

Tags: pandas, pivot, max, multi-index, argmax

df.head().info()

```
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id    5 non-null object
date-hr               5 non-null object
channel           5 non-null object
hr                5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
```

Actual *date-hr* looks something like

```
'2017-02-14--15'
```

*id* is a **string**

I have a df like:

```
User-ID | Date-hr | Channel | Hr

U1       D1-10      C1        10
U1       D1-11      C2        11
U1       D1-10      C1        10
U1       D1-10      C3        10
U1       D1-10      C1        10
U1       D1-11      C3        11
U1       D1-11      C2        11

..
```

when I apply pivot operation with user-id as index and columns as

```
['date-hr', 'channel']
```

using **count** as the aggregation function.

I get 1 row for every user with the primary index as date-hr and all channels under that one date-hr value like:

```
    D1-10     D1-11 .....

    C1  C3    C2 C3 .....

U1  3    1    2   1 .....
```

Now what I require is max channel under every 'date-hr' with the count

```
    D1-10   D1-11 .....

    C1      C2    .....

U1  (C1,3)  (C2,2) .....
```

I can't figure it out how to get this transformation from my data.

Comment: Is possible omit first level of MultiIndex in columns in output?

Comment: After    df.pivot_table(index=['id'],columns=['date-hr','channel'], margins=True, aggfunc='count'), omit first level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom function:

```
print (df)
  User-ID Date-hr Channel  Hr
0      U1   D1-10      C1  10
1      U1   D1-11      C2  11
2      U1   D1-10      C1  10
3      U1   D1-10      C3  10
4      U2   D1-10      C1  10
5      U2   D1-11      C3  11
6      U2   D1-11      C2  11
6      U4   D7-11      C2  11

df = df.groupby(['User-ID','Date-hr', 'Channel'])['Hr'].count().unstack([1,2], fill_value=0)
print (df)
Date-hr D1-10    D1-11    D7-11
Channel    C1 C3    C2 C3    C2
User-ID                        
U1          2  1     1  0     0
U2          1  0     1  1     0
U4          0  0     0  0     1

def f(x):
    c = x.idxmax(axis=1).str[1]
    m = x.max(axis=1)
    s = pd.Series((list(zip(c, m))), index=x.index)
    return (s)

df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(f)
print (df)
Date-hr    D1-10    D1-11    D7-11
User-ID                           
U1       (C1, 2)  (C2, 1)  (C2, 0)
U2       (C1, 1)  (C2, 1)  (C2, 0)
U4       (C1, 0)  (C2, 0)  (C2, 1)
```

Comment: @NikhilVerma - I test it in last pandas version `0.23.0`, is possible upgrade?

Comment: Okay, I tried the same thing after updating pandas, same issue

Comment: I have updated the question with info about my initial df. Is there any issue in it?

Comment: @NikhilVerma - are data confidental?

Comment: I find possible problem, all `NaN`s per some group.

Comment: Yes, I just thought of that, I will try to fillna with 0

Comment: Where should I write **df=df.fillna(0)**?, tried that after the first **group by** and got the same error

Comment: There is another problem, soem values are omited, I find problem with `s = list(zip(c, m))`

Comment: oops, my solution was wrong, please check edited answer.

Comment: @NikhilVerma - Super :)